# Dynamically Create a Python Subclass in a Function

Tags: python

I want to write a function creating dynamic subclass.
For example:

```
def get_class(num):
    ...
    ...
    return _class
```

This function accepts an integer `num` and then constructs such a class

```
class Test(BaseClass):
    attr_1 = 1
    attr_2 = 1
    ...
    attr_num = 1
```

and return it.

I wonder whether this is possible WITHOUT writing a metaclass.

Comment: What is a "dynamic subclass" exactly?  Does `get_class()` return one of several predetermined classes, or an instance of one, or does it actually create entirely new types?

Comment: I _hope_ this is just a simple example to explain your question, because creating a bunch of classes merely to accommodate a variable number of attributes named like that does not look like a good design: it would be better to make a single class that stores those attributes in a tuple or list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `type` function to dynamically create a class. The [documentation for type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) pretty much describes exactly what you're trying to accomplish. Something like this:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    pass

def get_class(num):
    attrs = [('attr_%d' % i, 1) for i in range(num)]
    return type('Test', (BaseClass,), dict(attrs))
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the other answer, you can either use `type`, in which case you dynamically construct attributes:

```
def foo(num, **kwargs):
    kwargs.update({'num': num})
    return type('Foo', (BaseClass,), kwargs)
```

or if you dont need dynamic keys you can then simply manually instantiate a class:

```
def foo(num):
    class Foo(BaseClass):
        num = num
    return Foo
```